# Connection to a mangodb data base with flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, atlas

I tried to connect to my database with flutter to the server thx to mangodb. But i got an error my url connection isnt working so idk what s going on ...

I run this code

```dart
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

void main() async {
  var db = Db("mongodb+srv://user:password@insalertdatabase.lkxngp6.mongodb.net/eventbase?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
  await db.open();
  var collection = db.collection("event");
  // Use the collection here
  await db.close();
}
```

I got this error :

```
MongoDartError (MongoDart Error: Invalid scheme in uri: mongodb+srv://admin:admin@eventinsalertdatabase.lkxngp6.mongodb.net/eventbase?retryWrites=true&w=majority mongodb+srv)
```

this is the structure of my database

https://ibb.co/MGv40jp

Comment: Did you tried with local db? Check if the issue is with remote db only. I think the issue is with the schema you defined. Also try with defining Port as well. You haven't defined port in your schema..

Comment: In every site i ahve seen when you want to connect to the remote server you dont need to define a port and i dont see the think between connecting to a local database and a remote server it s not the same, the syntax of the link arent the same.